# Who shall be the winner?

Tags: chess, retrograde-analysis, sliding-blocks

There are two questions to answer here:

1. Who will win this game of chess?
2. What were the last 96 individual moves (ply) by both sides? The solution is unique.

**Gyula Breyer The Chess Amateur 1922, Correction By Gerd Wilts**

[image]

Comment: Is the board orientation a given or do we have to work that out too?

Comment: Here's a [link](https://lichess.org/editor/KB6/QpN1p2p/r1pkP3/Rqp1p3/bRP5/brP5/pPP5/NB6_w_-_-_0_1) if anyone wants to play.

Comment: Are we given whose turn it is?

Comment: May I know why we post this here when it is already solved elsewhere. Is it fine to post solved questions here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This game is drawn due to the [50 move rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifty-move_rule).

Previous moves, going backwards:

> 1. ... Qb6b5
>  2. Rb5a5 Qa5b6
>  3. Rb6b5 Bb5a4
>  4. Ra4b4 Qb4a5
>  5. Ra5a4 Ba4b5
>  6. Rb5b6 Rb6a6
>  7. Ra6a5 Qa5b4
>  8. Rb4b5 Bb5a4
>  9. Ra4b4 Bb4a3
>  10. Ra3a4 Qa4a5
>  11. Ra5a6 Ba6b5
>  12. Rb5a5 Ba5b4
>  13. Rb4b5 Qb5a4
>  14. Ra4a3 Ra3b3
>  15. Rb3b4 Bb4a5
>  16. Ra5a4 Qa4b5
>  17. Rb5a5 Ba5b4
>  18. Rb4b3 Qb3a4
>  19. Ra4b4 Bb4a5
>  20. Ra5b5 Bb5a6
>  more coming

Comment: Accidentally submitted early, still working on it

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't seem too hard to trace it back just haven't had the time

Answer (score 1):

PARTIAL SOLUTION:

> white will gain a clear material advantage and win the game 
>  1. Nxa6+ Kxe6 2. Bxa2 Qxa5 3. Nxb3 Qd8 4. Naxc5+ Kf5
>  5. bxa3 Qd1 6. Qxa4 Kg4 7. Na5 Qa1 8. Qb3 b6
>  9. Rxb6 Kh3 10. Rb7 Qg1 11. Nd3 Qg5 12. c5 Kg2
>  13. Qe6 Qg3 14. Rb1 Qf3 15. Qxe5 Qxd3 16. cxd3 Kf3
>  17. Qg3+ Ke2 18. Rb2+ Kd1 19. Qg1#